# WQL to find files in a directory

Tags: wmi, wmi-query, wql

How do you find files inside directories with WMI Query Language?

This is what I have so far:

```
select * from Cim_DataFile
 where path = "\\\\C:\\Users\\name\\"
```

The query returns no results.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must remove the drive of the `Path` property and specify that value in the `Drive` property, so rewrote your WQL sentence  to

> SELECT * from Cim_DataFile  where path = "\\Users\\name\\"  and
>   Drive="C:"